# How to download attachment file in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

I am using postman for API calls as I am trying to download on batch thousands of files from a database.

`https://website.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/incidents/439006/fileAttachments/?download`

This creates the call but I then have to click save response -> save to a file to download the attachment.

Is this something that's possible in postman?

My IT department is very strict with downloading development environments I only have postman and R Studio. I know you can use RCURL potentially but considering I don't know how to use CURL I don't know where to start.

What I want to do is download any attachment (if it exists) for a number of keys.

And in a loop call the file:

> i = o
>
> Start loop i in n#rows(file)
>
> i = i+
>
> key = key(i)

`https://website.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/incidents/{key}/fileAttachments/?download`

> Save to file (named key).
>
> Loop

I can't get it to work, I want a file full of thousands of downloads each called the number of the key.

Comment: The question is unclear!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command in linux system.

```
curl -v "https://website.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/incidents/{key}/fileAttachments/?download"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command in linux system.

```
curl -v "https://website.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/incidents/{key}/fileAttachments/?download"
```

Also you can try to send the request from postman and try to save that response.

Let me know if that works.